# Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array):

> Given an array of integers `nums` sorted in ascending order, find the starting and ending position of a given `target` value.
>
> If `target` is not found in the array, return `[-1, -1]`.
>
> You must write an algorithm with `O(log n)` runtime complexity.

I am writing this code:

```
var searchRange = function(nums, target) {
  nums = nums.sort((a, b) => (a-b))
  let result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == target) {
      result.push(i)
    } else {
     result = [-1, -1]
    }
  }

  return result
};
 
console.log(searchRange([5,7,7,8,8,10], 8));
```

It should return:

```
[3, 4]
```

but it returns:

```
[-1, -1]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function searchRange(r,n){
  var s = r.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
  return [s.indexOf(n), s.lastIndexOf(n)];
}

console.log('result 1',searchRange([5,7,7,8,8,10], 8))
console.log('result 2',searchRange([5,7,7,6,6,10], 8))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know what is wrong in my code.

Comment: You don't need to loop for it. And indexOf returns -1 if not found...

Comment: This should not be accepted as answer. It doesn't meet the requirements of time complexity mentioned in the question.

Comment: joopmicroop thanks  I understand now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` code is wiping out results from the previous iteration of the loop.

However, your code is not efficient:

First, it calls `sort` on an array that is given to be already sorted: so leave that out.

Secondly, as your code is visiting *every* element in the array, you still get a time complexity of O(n), not O(logn).

To get O(logn) you should implement a binary search, and then perform a search to find the *start* of the range, and another to find the end of it.

Here is how that could work:

```js
function binarySearch(nums, target) {
    let low = 0;
    let high = nums.length;
    
    while (low < high) {
        let mid = (low + high) >> 1; // half way
        if (nums[mid] > target) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return high; // first index AFTER target
}

function searchRange(nums, target) {
    let end = binarySearch(nums, target);
    let start = binarySearch(nums, target - 1);
    return start === end ? [-1, -1] : [start, end - 1];
}
 
console.log(searchRange([5,7,7,8,8,10], 8));
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop does not have a good exit condition. Loop iterates till the last element and if the last element does not match, it sets -1,-1 into the result.
Intermediate values of result are ignored.

Other problems:

- You're given a sorted array, so don't sort it again. That's heavy.
- When you iterate over all elements, it has O(n) time complexity.

Solution:

- Binary search to find any one occurence of the element - save the index where the value is found.
- Use the index found to check left and right adjacent elements in the original array to find the start and end positions.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, its just your logic. You are setting `result` to [-1, -1] if ANY index of `nums` after the last `target` index is not equal to the `target`. So you want to have the check outside of the `for` loop.

```
var searchRange = function(nums, target) {
    nums = nums.sort((a, b) => (a-b));
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == target) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }

    return (result.length == 0) ? [-1, -1] : result;
};
 
 console.log(searchRange([5,7,7,8,8,10], 8));
```

Note: This will not be the final solution because this will return EVERY index that contains `target`

Answer (score 0):

> **Dart**

```
   if (nums.isEmpty || !nums.contains(target)) {
      return [-1, -1];
    } else {
      return [nums.indexOf(target), nums.lastIndexOf(target)];
    }
```